# Entity не пишет ID в бд

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Есть проблема. Есть класс в который заполняют на странице, а затем, я записываю пришедшие данные  в бд через контекст. Проблема в том, что entity не пишет id в базу, а присваивает порядковый id. Все остальное пишет хорошо.В чем проблема?

```
public class Order {
    [Key]
    public int id { get; set; }
    public DateTime date { get; set; }
    public string Customer { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }
    public Order() {
        Products = new List<Product>();
    }
}
```

Запись:

```
db.Orders.Add(order);
db.SaveChanges();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В EF, по умолчанию, целочисленный primary key является автогенерируемым — т.е. он инкрементируется на каждый `insert`. Чтобы отвадить его от этого поведения достаточно добавить следующий атрибут:

```
[Key]
[DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
public int id { get; set; }
```